# How to avoid messages like "Profiler Agent Warning: Failed to lookup cached class org/apache/derby..." when profiling with visualvm?

Tags: java, class, profile, visualvm, caching

When trying to monitor a Java application using visualvm I can't obtain useful information, because a lot of my classes (but not only mine) can't be instrumented, displaying the following message:

Profiler Agent Warning: Failed to lookup cached class org/apache/derby/impl/services/locks/ActiveLock

Thus, the profiler doesn't show any information about the method invocation to those classes :-(

Is there any workaround for this problem?

Some details:

- OS: Linux 64 bit (Ubuntu 8.10)
- Java: sun jdk 1.6.0.14 (64 bit)
- VisualVM: 1.1.1
- Application: running on top of Tomcat 5.5.17

Answer (score 0):

This problem should be fixed in VisualVM 1.2.2. For more details see [issue #345](https://visualvm.dev.java.net/issues/show_bug.cgi?id=345).

Comment: I have this problem also in 1.3.9.